# Geokit location undefined method `lat' with :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geokit

I am trying to find all the Drivers within the distance of the Order 'pickup_address', as explained in the GeoKit guide https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails#using-through

Drivers have locations through UserLocations and Orders have locations through PickupAddresses.

I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in OrdersController#show
undefined method `lat' for "Order"
```

Order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

 has_paper_trail

 # an order MUST contain the following 
 validates_presence_of :description 
 validates_presence_of :weight
 validates_presence_of :length
 validates_presence_of :width
 validates_presence_of :height 
 validates_presence_of :pickup_address
 validates_presence_of :dropoff_address
 validates_presence_of :pickup_contact
 validates_presence_of :dropoff_contact

 # each order should have one address for pickup and one address for dropoff 
 has_one :pickup_address, :as => :locatable  # also works for belongs_to associations
 acts_as_mappable :through => :pickup_address
 has_one :dropoff_address, inverse_of: :order

 # each order needs two contacts 
 has_one :pickup_contact, inverse_of: :order
 has_one :dropoff_contact, inverse_of: :order
end
```

PickupAddress.rb

```
class PickupAddress < Address
  belongs_to :locatable, :polymorphic => true
  acts_as_mappable
end
```

I also added the acts_as_mappable to Address.rb to see if the code would work, but nothing changed.

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :locatable, :polymorphic => true
  acts_as_mappable

  # Attributes to have a valid address for Driver/Geocoder
  validates_presence_of :street1
  validates_presence_of :city
  validates_presence_of :state
  validates_presence_of :country
  validates_presence_of :postal
  validates_presence_of :type

  # Geocoder conversion for easier calculations 
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode

  # address used by Geocoder and condensed display 
  def full_address
    [street1, city, state, country].compact.join(', ')
  end 
end
```

This is the line I'm getting an error on:

```
@drivers = Driver.within(5, :origin => @order)
```

And, for reference, here is my Driver mapping:

Driver.rb

```
class Driver < User
  has_many :orders
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # each user has a location, drivers first, then can expand later 
  has_one :user_location, :as => :locatable
  acts_as_mappable :through => :user_location
end
```

UserLocation.rb

```
class UserLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :locatable, :polymorphic => true
  acts_as_mappable :default_units => :miles

  #reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
end
```

Finally, the schema:

```
create_table "user_locations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.float    "lat"
t.float    "lng"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_locations_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "type"
t.string   "street1"
t.string   "street2"
t.string   "city"
t.string   "state"
t.string   "postal"
t.string   "country"
t.integer  "order_id"
t.float    "lat"
t.float    "lng"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_order_id", using: :btree
end
```

OrdersController.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  layout 'dashboard'

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_action :load_resource

  # insert generic boring stuff

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:invoice, :description, :weight, :length, :width, :height, :account_id, :driver_id, :status, 
      pickup_address_attributes: [:street1, :street2, :city, :state, :postal, :country],
      dropoff_address_attributes: [:street1, :street2, :city, :state, :postal, :country],
      pickup_contact_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :phone],
      dropoff_contact_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :phone])
    end

    def load_resource 
      case params[:action].to_sym
      when :show
        if current_user.is_admin? 
          @drivers = Driver.within(5, :origin => @order)
        end 
      end 
    end 
end
```

NEW ERROR after changing my latitude and longitude columns with 'lat' and 'lng' WITH SUGGESTED CHANGES:

```
NEW error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_locations"
LINE 1: ...M "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Driver') AND (user_locat...
                                                         ^
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Driver') AND (user_locations.lat IS NOT NULL AND user_locations.lng IS NOT NULL) AND (user_locations.lat>29.61103991439227 AND user_locations.lat<38.28523108560773 AND user_locations.lng>-88.97349091777367 AND user_locations.lng<-78.5259326822263) AND (((ACOS(least(1,COS(0.5925067393881714)*COS(-1.4617082185063466)*COS(RADIANS(user_locations.lat))*COS(RADIANS(user_locations.lng))+ COS(0.5925067393881714)*SIN(-1.4617082185063466)*COS(RADIANS(user_locations.lat))*SIN(RADIANS(user_locations.lng))+ SIN(0.5925067393881714)*SIN(RADIANS(user_locations.lat))))*3963.1899999999996) <= 300))
```

Comment: I was going off the guide, located here: https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails

Comment: You need to provide the orders controller.

Comment: Added the controller just for you!

Comment: but pickup_address doen't have a lat and lng attribute, how do you know the pickup address point?

Comment: Pickup address does have a lat and lng attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear here how the method that you are trying to run works

@drivers = Driver.within(5, :origin => @order)

the origin attribute that you are sending to the method needs to be an instance of a model with lat and lng attribute and it seems like order doesn't have them, on the example, you have two models that have those attributes `addresses` and `user_locations` just change @order for the instance that have your lat and lng where you want the drivers

Comment: The new error: undefined method `latitude' for #<Order:0x007f8c29af2e88>

Comment: add the through :pickup_address to that line too, sorry

Comment: Changed the column name for good measure after trying the additives above, and received the same error.

Comment: Same error when adding the :through when I add that to the Order. I added it to the PickupAddress.rb originally.

Comment: Sorry we were looking for something more complicated but it seems more simple now, just change on this line 
@drivers = Driver.within(5, :origin => @order.pickup_address), if this works, I can edit the answer to make clear why this was happening

Comment: undefined method `lat' for #<PickupAddress:0x007fdd40d9fec0>

Comment: Update: I had to re-migrate the column name change

Comment: I added the new error to the question above, it was too long for a comment.

Comment: edited, just to clarify in general, if you don't have it clear now, please edit the question with logic about what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0):

the `through` in the gem has long time issue as in [this](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/issues/92)

the solution is using explicit join between your `model` and `geokit` method calls

`driver` is subclass of `user` and `user` has geokit's method and mappable through `user_location`

so for `Driver.within(5, :origin => @order)` to works you need to write it like this

`Driver.joins(:user_location).within(5, :origin => @order)`